nicematrix & RTL languages
I try to compile an example of the documentation of the nicematrix package, but it fails with right-to-left languages.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, nicematrix}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

% \setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
\setdefaultlanguage{persian}
% \setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[corners]
& \Block{1-2}{columns} \\
\Block{2-1}{rows}
& cell 1 1 & cell 1 2 \\
& cell 2 1 & cell 2 2
\CodeAfter
\TikzEveryCell{offset=1pt,draw}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}

If I comment out the line
\setdefaultlanguage{...}

it compiles without error.

Welcome to TeX.SE! What did the manual say? Have you contacted the author?

Which error do you get when you compile your example?
